# Why MES2106 is having a lower price than MES2103?

Tags: futures, spx

MES refers to Micro E-mini S&P 500 Index Futures

As my understanding of futures goes, future price increases with contract end time because otherwise, one can buy the longer expiring contract and sell the short expiring future, then start shorting the underlying assets of the index to achieve arbitrage.

However, it seems the current price of MES2103 is 3899.25 and MES2106 is 3887.75.

SP500 is a total return index so it is not like dividend is a factor on the index value.

For later strikes future (like MES2112 has 3875.5 and MES 2203 has 3861.5) I assume it is due to liquidity and trading restriction issue. But it seems MES2106 doesn't have this problem.

What did I miss?

Comment: From what I know, the S&P 500 index is not a total return index, it does not include dividend returns. Since S&P 500 dividend yield is generally higher than the risk free rate, longer dated futures are discounted more.

Comment: Current S&P500 dividend yield is 1.57% https://ycharts.com/indicators/sp_500_dividend_yield , current SOFR rate  is 0.03 https://apps.newyorkfed.org/markets/autorates/SOFR . So $(r-d)$ is negative. Recall that $F=S e^{(r-d)T}$. So "longer dated futures are discounted more".

Comment: Yeah, it seems once again investopia is not the best source of information. I am lied by https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/total_return_index.asp